# Deploy a windows phone 8.1 company app on a windows 10 mobile device

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a company app built and signed with the symantec cert for windows phone 8.1. My client tried installing it on a windows 10 mobile device and it keeps saying "pending" with no option to uninstall. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had several apps just pending doing nothing. I switched off the automatic update of date and time and restarted the phone, then the apps resume the download/installation

Settings -> Time & Language -> Date & Time -> Disable Set date and time automatically